# JPA commit() row skiped after persist()

Tags: java, jpa

I'm try to add a new entity on my database, but everytime I try the commit row is skiped after the persist().

```
public T salvar(T t) {
        EntityManager em = daoHelper.getEM();
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            if (t.getId() == null) {
                em.persist(t);
                em.getTransaction().commit();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
        return t;
    }
```

I don't know what is wrong, because the object t is complete.

Edit 1: These are my entity atributes

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "idItem")
    private Integer idItem;
    @Column(name = "pedidoData")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date pedidoData;
    @Size(max = 9)
    @Column(name = "pedidoEnderecoCep")
    private String pedidoEnderecoCep;
    @Column(name = "pedidoEnderecoNumero")
    private Integer pedidoEnderecoNumero;
    @Size(max = 85)
    @Column(name = "pedidoEnderecoBairro")
    private String pedidoEnderecoBairro;
```

And this is the object that I'm trying to add:

[image]

Comment: It only happens with one entity. I just tested and the same code worked with another entity

Comment: Can you share the sequence of inputs you are sending to this method?

Comment: @codeLover Sure. I edited the question with more information

Comment: If commit is "skipped" then a `Throwable` is thrown. End of. So debug why an exception is thrown. Basic java.

Answer (score 0):

On a higher level, it seems the issue is because of the place you have kept your **commit** statement. You have kept it inside the if condition, so the **commit** happens only when the if condition is satisfied. For instance, in the sample input data shared by you id is not null, therefore, **if** condition is not satisfied, thus, **commit** won't take place, on the contrary if you will send entity with **null id**, **commit** will take place. You should move the commit statement outside the if block as:

```
 if (t.getId() == null) {
      em.persist(t);              
 }
 em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: The commit() row still been skipped

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you mean by " commit() row still been skipped "

Comment: When I get to persist() row and click to move to the next row it goes directly to em.close() on debug mode. It's like em.getTransaction().commit(); doesn't exist.

Comment: you mean a Throwable is thrown. So DEBUG YOUR CODE and look at what Throwable is thrown!